# Python - Datetime module, constructors and variable type

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to get Python, especially how it works. I was digging into datetime module, and classes, that are part of it - date, datetime, timedelta etc. There are few question, that I don't catch. Lets base on below example:

```
import datetime
object1 = datetime.date.today()
object2 = datetime.date(2020, 8, 19)
print(object1, object2)
2022-02-12 2020-08-19
print (type(object1), type(object2))
<class 'datetime.date'> <class 'datetime.date'>
print (object1 - object2)
542 days, 0:00:00
```

The first question is - how it is possible to create object in two ways - first is (as I assume) by using **__ init __** constructor (object2), and the second is by ... - there comes a question. How calling method **today()** directly from class **datetime.date** is able to create new instance of this class?

My second question is - before, when I was dealing with classes, there wasnt any exact value of object, that I had to use, I was only looking at methods and variables inside this object. The return value of instructions (constructors?) **date.today** and **date(y, m, d)** is **datetime.date** class. But what is the exact type of value, that object1 and object2 contains - how I am able to add them, generally to make any mathematical operation on it with **sense**.

Comment: Please post code as text,  not as image.

Comment: `today` is a `@classmethod` which internally simply does something akin to `return date(…)`.

Comment: Python allows each class to define itself how to work with operators; in this case `date` has a `__sub__` method which implements the behavior for the `-` operator.